# Does Platform event subscription applies to PE Triggers too?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, platform-event

Consider this scenario. I have a trigger on Platform event named as `SOject_Upsert_Data__e`

```
trigger SObjectUpsertData on SOject_Upsert_Data__e (after insert) {
    // Some Logic
}
```

And I am raising Platform events from flows wherever I need to update any record in salesforce.
The reason is because to better capture Lock row exceptions and retry them. And also we have many flows, like (1000) and have made it very complex unnecessary. So a cleanup is very hard and very time consuming and many issues occurs because of lock row.

Question: There might be more than 50K requests coming to the triggers in 24 hour period. So my doubt is does 50K limit applies here too? And whats the difference between `Event Delivery` and `Event Publishing`, and under which event does triggers fall?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really [link to the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) you reference. Here's what I believe to be the relevant passage:

> Non-CometD clients, including Apex triggers, processes, and flows, don’t count against the event delivery limit. The number of event messages that an Apex trigger, process, or flow can process depends on how long the processing takes for each subscriber. The longer the processing time, the longer it takes for the subscriber to reach the tip of the event stream.

Note that most discussion of limitations within that link discusses CometD subscribers, which are not what you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Event Delivery refers to [CometD subscribers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_cometd.htm) such as:

- Lightning Web Components that use [`lightning-emp-api`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) to receive Platform Events
- Visualforce pages that use a CometD implementation to subscribe to Platform Events, as in [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_interactive_vfp_create_VF_page.htm)
- [External clients](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm) that use the Streaming API to receive events

Delivery of the Platform Event to a trigger does not count against the 50K limit.